# No CSV File is created after Process Execution

Tags: powershell, csv

I am not new to Powershell, but I am new to making scripts in Powershell myself.

I had to make a simple script which takes all of our employees at work and a bit of info about them, and then output a CSV file with this information. But when I run the code below, nothing happens. The ISE simply executes the process, a second passes and it's done. Then no CSV file is created.

```
PROCESS {
    $path = Split-Path -parent "C:\Users\omitted\Desktop"
    $pathexist = Test-Path -Path $path
    If($pathexist -eq $false) {
        New-IOItem -type directory -Path $path
    }
    $csvreportfile = $path + "\ALLADUsers_.csv"

    #import the AD Module
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Medarbejdere,OU=Users,OU=omitted,DC=omitted,DC=local" -Properties MemberOf -Filter * |
        Select-Object @{ Label = "First Name";   Expression = { $_.GivenName } },
                      @{ Label = "Last Name";    Expression = { $_.Surname } },
                      @{ Label = "Display Name"; Expression = { $_.DisplayName } },
                      @{ Label = "Logon Name";   Expression = { $_.SamAccountName } },
                      @{ Label = "Job Title";    Expression = { $_.Title } },
                      @{ Label = "Description";  Expression = { $_.Description } },
                      @{ Label = "Department";   Expression = { $_.Department } } |

        #Export CSV Report
        Export-Csv -Path $csvreportfile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think `Label` should be replaced with `Name`, for a start. What is `New-IOItem`? I believe you could use `New-Item` instead. Where did you find this code? It looks like a bit old.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a PROCESS block, but I suspect the issue is more likely to be that the pipeline is empty once you get to the Export-CSV. Try stepping back in the pipeline and running in the console in chunks. E.g remove the Export-CSV part and see if you get results, if not remove the Select-Object of the pipeline and see if you get results..

Comment: I think "Label" is an acceptable alternative actually, although Name is the preferred standard and what is in the documentation.

Comment: @Mark I tried to look up a quick example of how to do what I wanted to do, and it seemed like the Process block was necessary. I've never had to write Powershell myself, I've only used Powershell Scripts before so forgive my noobness :P

Comment: @Mark: thanks, wasn't so sure about this.

Comment: @Vipar I think you only need to use a Process block when you're writing a function that is accepting pipeline input (and as a result when you pipe in multiple objects the process block gets performed once per input). It doesn't seem to apply in your case so i'd just remove it.

Comment: The issue might be that as a result of using `-properties MemberOf` that is the only property being returned by Get-ADUser. Might be wrong tho, don't have a machine with access to AD to test on right now. In fact as you don't use "memberof" in your select, i'd drop the `-properties MemberOf` part altogether.

Comment: @Mark So I ran the Get-ADUser part again, without using Select-Object, and it definitely returns a lot of data, so there is something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#moved the Parent parameter to the end to more clearly distinguish Path's value from Parent (switch).  
$path = Split-Path -Path "C:\Users\omitted\Desktop" -Parent 

#Since we don't refer to $PathExist again, skipped the assignment and put the test directly in the condition
If(Test-Path -Path $path) { 
    #Corrected Type; was `New-IOItem`
    New-Item -type directory -Path $path
}

#use Join-Path when joining paths, to avoid issues with too many/too few slashes
$csvreportfile = Join-Path $path "ALLADUsers_.csv"

#import the AD Module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Added other properties which wouldn't be returned by default (see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx for a list of all properties / those in Cyan are the only ones which don't need to be listed on the Properties parameter)
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Medarbejdere,OU=Users,OU=omitted,DC=omitted,DC=local" -Properties MemberOf, Title, Description, Department -Filter * |
    Select-Object @{ Label = "First Name";   Expression = { $_.GivenName } },
                  @{ Label = "Last Name";    Expression = { $_.Surname } },
                  @{ Label = "Display Name"; Expression = { $_.DisplayName } },
                  @{ Label = "Logon Name";   Expression = { $_.SamAccountName } },
                  @{ Label = "Job Title";    Expression = { $_.Title } },
                  @{ Label = "Description";  Expression = { $_.Description } },
                  @{ Label = "Department";   Expression = { $_.Department } } `
| Export-Csv -Path $csvreportfile -NoTypeInformation #moved this so that the pipeline feeds into export-csv; the whitespace had made this statement invalid previously
```

I've added comments inline explaining the changes I've made.

Regarding the `PROCESS` section, that's not needed if you're running this directly in the script's body.  I'd normally include this if I were defining a function/cmdlet (see https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-function-input.html).

Comment: Yeah that worked out. Thanks. I see the mistake now :')